# Count occurences of words for each element of a list in python

Tags: python

I have a code which gives me count of strings in a list.

```
names=['Deepak is a boy','Reema is short','John is tall','Deepak is shy','Munna is naughty','Reema','Deepak is shy','Amit is hilarious','John is tall','Reema is short']

nm=input('Enter the word you want to count: ')
count=names.count(nm)
print('count = ', count)
```

Output:

```
Enter the word you want to count: John is tall
count =  2
```

However I want to find occurences of a single word for ex:shy. If I type shy then I get count as zero.
Can someone help me with how to get count of individual words.
Expected output for word shy:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names=['Deepak is a boy','Reema is short','John is tall','Deepak is shy','Munna is naughty','Reema','Deepak is shy','Amit is hilarious','John is tall','Reema is short']
nm=input('Enter the word you want to count: ')
occurences = [name.count(nm) for name in names]
count = sum(occurences) # This gives total number of occurences
print(occurences) # This will print out all occurences of input string
print('count = ', count) # This prints total number of occurences, although not requested may become useful for you.
```

This answer will allow for if names occurrences is not == 1 but greater as suggested in comments..

Comment: Note that the desired output is the list of occurrences, not the total.

Comment: Thanks, I will amend the answer to suit that.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list and count occurences for each text in `names`.

```
c = []
for name in names:
    c.append(name.count(nm))
```

Comment: A list comprehension does this much more succinctly.